# PyVelest.py Compilation on MacBook Pro M2 Running Python 2.7: _GEOSArea issue

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap, geos, macbookpro-touch-bar

I've been attempting to compile PyVelest.py using Python 2.7 on my MacBook Pro M2.

```
(base) isaacguerra@MacBook-Pro-de-Isaac PyVelest % python2 PyVelest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PyVelest.py", line 26, in
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/init.py", line 53, in
import _geoslib
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_GEOSArea'
```

I've tried various solutions, including restarting my MacBook Pro M2, but I'm still encountering issues. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?